# Missing "Mono for Android SDKs" option in MonoDevelop's preferences

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

I was unable to locate the "Mono for Android SDKs" preferences option when following the Mono for Android for Mac installation instructions.

### troubleshooting steps I've tried:

After completing installation of the evaluation copy of Mono for Android for Mac I restarted MonoDevelop (version 2.4.2) and still didn't have the option available.  I rebooted my Mac but that did not trigger MonoDevelop to expose the option either.  I tried reinstalling the Mono for Android addin also.

Anyone struggled with the same problem?  Let me know what you tried.  Thanks!

Comment: further troubleshooting steps... 

I installed the lastest MonoDevelop beta and the preferences option appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's funny to answer my own question, but on further troubleshooting steps...

I installed the lastest MonoDevelop beta and the preferences option appeared.

Comment: If you were following these instructions, you should have noticed it says that MonoDevelop 2.10.1 or later is required: http://mono-android.net/Installation/Installation_for_Mac